# How to search internet with Python?

Tags: python, search

I want to write a program that searches through a fairly large website and extracts certain things. I've had a couple online Python courses, but neither said anything about how to access the internet with Python. I have no idea where I ought to start with this.

Comment: You'll need to read about HTTP, HTML and probably JS/PHP/etc, probably at list dip your toes in a more robust understanding of DOMs, then learn about text parsing/processing.  Look at urllib/urllib2/httplib/requests/etc, and something like BeautifulSoup or even Selenium, depending upon the complexity and interactivity you need.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/internet)? First result on Google for "Python Internet" by the way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have first to read about the standard python library [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

Once you are comfortable with the basic ideas behind this lib you can try [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which is much easier to interact with the web especially APIs. I suggest using it in parallel with [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie) to test out queries quick and dirty from command line.

If you go a little further building a librairy or an engine to crawl the web you will need some sort of asynchronous programming, I recommend starting with [Gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)

Finally, if you want to create a crawler/bot you can take a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). You should however start with basic libraries before diving into this one as it can get quite complex

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a web crawler/scraper. What sorts of things do you want to pull? Images? Links? Just the job for a web crawler/scraper.

Start there, there should be lots of articles on Stackoverflow that will help you implement details such as connecting to the internet (getting a web response).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping) article.

Answer (score 2):

There is much more in the internet than just websites, but I assume that you just want to crawl some html pages and extract data from them. You have many many options to solve that problem. Just some starting points:

- urllib2 from the standard library
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests (much easier and more user friendly)
- http://scrapy.org/ (a very good crawling framework)
- http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ (library to extract data from html)