# What is DOM generated code?

Tags: html, firefox, dom, browser

I am obviously new to HTML and Web Browsers and python too. I installed the Web Developer extension in Firefox and noticed that in addition to the "View Source" option there are two additional "View Generated Source" and "View Frame Source" options. What are these? Why should they be different?

1. I have no idea what a generated source is.
2. Aren't frames part of the page? If so why do I need a separate "View Frame Source" option? Does it mean that the regular "View Page Source" will not show source for all the elements in the page?
3. If I want to see the code that is executed/used to show me a page which option should I look at and why?
4. If I want to get this code in python using the requests module how do I get these various sources?

Comment: Question 4 seems like it would fare better as a separate, if related, question, since it's the only one that involves Python in any way.

Answer (score 2):

HTML code can be modified dynamically be javascript. "View Generated Source" will show you the HTML as in it is current state that might have been modified by javascript and differs from the html delivered by the server. So this is interesting for the debugging javascript applications.

"View Frame Source" is for websites that are using HTML framesets. Such such sites are a composite of multiple single html sites that are displayed together at one page. Is an older attempt of web design but still widely deployed. So such sites can look like a simple page with the menu on the left side and the content beside it. Using framesets there would be a menu.html and a content.html. Both html sites can be displayed separately in 'Web Developer Toolbar' while clicking with the right mouse button on it and select "Show frame source"

Question 1 and 2 should being answered. Question 3.

> If I want to see the code that is executed/used to show me a page which option should I look at and why?

Answer use "View Generated Source..." as this will give you the html you are actually seeing diplayed in browser regardless if it is generated by javascript or not.

---

Unfortunately I'm not a python expert so question 4 keeps open

Answer (score 0):

The generated source is the result of the frame source that is fetched by the browser then the execution of the javascript on the browser to modify this page.

To understand more how browsers get an html page compared to a program check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775702/707949

Then to get the sourge html page check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799102/707949

And to get the generated html source, check the end of the first answer